Why is an empty string returned by Airflow Jinjia template recognized as true value?
I have got the following DAG. Trying to get a param by template, and do some operation depending on whether it is empty.
with DAG(
    'tutorial',
    start_date= dates.days_ago(1),
    params={
        "STR": "",
    },
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
) as dag:
    def template(str, use_str):
        return f"echo value:{str}, bool: {bool(str)}"

    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="t1",
        bash_command=template("{{ params.STR }}")
    )

The output is
echo value:, bool: true

Why is an empty string not false?
